# Dymola crashes very often

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am using Dymola to build dynamic models, but in my experience, dymola crashes very often, especially after using it after a few hours, sometimes when I change the view to simulation or model, it would crash without any signs. I could meet this issue 3-5 times a day. It is not a big problem, but it is quite annoying when I forget to save the model.

Have anyone experience the same situation? Is this normal?

Comment: I can confirm that I'm having similar issues with Dymola 2020x - far less frequently though. As far as I can tell, this is a known issue. I'm sure it would be highly appreciated if you could provide additional information on how these crashes can be reproduced!

Comment: It is hard to tell how it actually happens now. In my experience, sometimes dymola crashes when I finish a simulation and try to open another model, or when I change some parameters and try to change to the simulation view. I would keep this question open and try to record the situation when the crash happens in the future. Hopefully I could provide some more useful information.

Comment: We are having similar issues, however, it seems that it is hardware dependent. For people who work in the same group (they open the same libs almost everyday), some crashes everyday, some seldom encounter this issue. For me myself, I encounter this issue usually when I try to expand a library/package tree, I guess that's when Dymola tries to search for dependencies

Comment: One more thing that bothers me is that when I try to search for some component in the package browser, it often crashes. @HangYu  Does Dymola crashes less when using a computer with better hardware?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this a problem best resolved by submitting a bug report to Dymola technical support?

Comment: Originally I thought the crash issue is because my setting in dymola is wrong. But it appears that some other people also have the same problem, right now I am not sure what I do would cause the crashes. Maybe after I got some more details I would send a bug report.

Comment: To which the counter-argument is that if they may help you find the relevant information.